# OCR, как распознать на фотографии только машинный текст, напечатанный в программе?

Tags: python, распознавание-символов, pytesseract

В программе есть определенная фотография и к ней нанесен текст, можно ли как-то отсканировать только ее? Могу ли я каким-то образом стереть фон или что-то в этом роде? Может быть, вы сможете как-нибудь разбить его на слои, как в photoshop? Я не могу прикрепить фотографию.

Я попробовал EasyOCR, кажется, это почти работает, но если текст наносится поверх текста самой фотографии, то нет. Исходя из этого, я хотел бы предварительно обработать фотографию таким образом, чтобы на ней оставался только текст, напечатанный на машинке в программе, который легко сканировать. Пример на другой фотографии, на которой нет необходимости использовать ТЕСТОВЫЙ текст 102, но при сканировании фотографии текст перезаписывается текстом с фотографии.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для качественного распознавания, картинка должна быть не в jpeg. Далее переводите в HSV, cv2.inRange выбираете красное и подаете в tesseract.